# How to open the Facebook login window in new Tab on clicking the Like Button

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-like

How can we open the `Facebook` window in new `Tab` instead of opening in new `window`?

### My HTML is below

```
<div style="position: relative; top: 3px;" id="likeButton">
        <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" style="border: none;
            overflow: hidden; width: 260px; height: 35px;" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http:\\localhost\login.aspx|@&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;
          show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=35">
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

**Issue is** - On clicking the `Like Button`, opens the `Facebook` login window in new Window. How can I open it in new `Tab`

My JSFiddle is **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/QDxdQ/)**

Comment: Whether popups are opened in separate windows or in tabs is mostly a matter of browser configuration.

Comment: @CBroe - It's a specific case actually. Please check my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QDxdQ/)

Comment: I can’t see what’s supposed to be specific about it? My browser opens a new tab, because I’ve configured it that way.

Comment: @CBroe - Can i make it programatic? So that no need to make the end-user understand these things as it's a web page so anybody may access it on Internet.

Comment: No, as @CBore wrote rather it opens in a new tab or new window has to do with user configuration in the browser. You have absolutely no control over this. The only way that you can control it is with a browser extension/plugin, then you'll get the necessary privileges.

Comment: @NitzanTomer - any link will be really appreciable for the same.

Comment: Here's something: http://bit.ly/LR0JzF

Comment: ok, Understood. can you also show this claim in written somewhere. Actually I have to fix this bug :)

Comment: There _is_ no “bug”, so _what_ are you trying to “fix” …?

Answer (score 6):

Try this code, its working for me.

```
<a style="position: absolute; top:0px; left: 0px; width:100px; height:40px; cursor:pointer;" href="https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&display=popup&social_plugin=like&external_page_url=http%3A%2F%2Finvalid.invalid%2F&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fuiserver.php%3Fmethod%3Dopt.inlike%26app_id%3D127760087237610%26display%3Dpopup%26social_plugin%3Dlike%26secure%3Dfalse%26protocol%3Dhttp%253A%26external_page_url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Finvalid.invalid%252F%26from_login%3D1%26client_id%3D127760087237610&rcount=1" target="_blank"></a>

<div style="position: ansolute; top: 0px;z-index:0; cursor:pointer;" id="likeButton">
        <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; width: 260px; height: 35px;z-index: 0;" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http:\\localhost\login.aspx|@&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp; show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=35"></iframe>

</div>​
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/JpWCf/

Change the **external_page_url** parameter from href.

Comment: +1 working fine in iE(9, 7), Firefox and Chrome. Need to set it in Safari and IE 8 also

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I have to agree with the other commenters. You can't control how the browser handles Facebook's request to open a new window in a specific size. By default, though, it will usually open as a small pop-up to honor the window size request.

What I did get to do was this, though: [An example to hijack the click on the Like button and open something else - in a new tab](http://jsfiddle.net/UUdt7/). This is not yet what you want but might help to get you started in the right direction.

You would now need to figure out a way to open a page that tries to like your page.

It really burns down to how bad you need this to happen in a new tab instead a pop-up. Maybe the decision that lead you to that requirement needs some rethinking?

Comment: Link is broker. still +1 for the help.

Comment: The link should work, it just seems that JSFiddle is down.
Please try again later if you think it could help.